# Call an external api and switch between 2 urls while maintainig only one connection

Tags: spring-boot, httpclient, connection-pooling

Using the `BasicHttpClientConnectionManager`, I came to notice that I can't switch between two different urls  because the contents remains the same when I deployed.

I thought `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` might make a change, but I came to know that with that the connection will remain valid but this is no the behavior I was looking for is there a way to make the request made switch between two urls using the `SSlcontext` and `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` as compounds to build the request and knowing that the url is stored in data base so I would look for it each time I call the external api

The second option inspired me but in my case I want to switch but if there is a thread safe solution with the sort of singleton I have tried to make a @service that extends `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` but this caused me bean instantiation failed and I don't know how to actually close and make sure that any call would be valid in the mean time

The last method is supposed to make the switch based on the URIBuilder returned from `uriBuilderInit()`

update -1

A transactional method in which I would call either basic or pooling httpclientConnectionManager ?

NB: the fact there is tree url that can post requested is also a problem due to the host limitation (2) but at least I will only ensure the swap between two at a time but only one connection would be maintained at a time

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just want to notice that the creation of some classes like singleton the way you use for `ConnectionManager` is redundant if you are using Spring Framework. BTW. Your class is already created as a singleton bean because it's annotated with `@Service` annotation.

Comment: You have a point but  I''m actually still hesitating between calling  keeping the extend so this also something I wanted to know

Comment: I came to notice that most of the code i have writen already exists in the class I was trying to extend and in result i came back to the choise between basic/pooling httpclientConnectionManager as i would be making request from an url at time